# How to recover files that i accidentally deleted the path of?

Tags: windows-10

I accidentally removed the path on some important files causing them to disappear from the folder where they were in in windows. Where did they go and how do I retrieve them?

Comment: Please explain the difference between deleting the path, and deleting the files. Also, please note there is already a very detailed question and answers for data recovery.

Comment: @music2myear - I absolutely agree with you here.  I wonder if they have just deleted a symlink?  No way of knowing without more information!

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but it wouldn't hurt to install "Everything" search tool and search the one or more of the files by name.  If you can't remember a file name, then maybe just the extension (*.docx for example) and sort by the date/time columns such that the newest time is at the top.